# How do I require one of the two Clap options?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I am trying to write a CLI in Rust with the help of Clap. My command has 2 arguments, I want to make that just one or another can be specified, ex: `command --command_a` or `command --command_b`

```
#[derive(Debug, clap::Args)]
#[clap(name = "command")]
pub struct MyCommand {
    /// Argument1.
    #[clap(long, short)]
    command_a: String,
    /// Argument2.
    #[clap(long, short)]
    command_b: String,
    /// other optional events.
    #[clap(name = "others", long)]
    other_commands: Option<String>,
}
```

I can make both optional by adding `command_a: Option<String>`, and then in the code check that at least one has been provided, but can I do that using Clap?

Comment: Check out the [ArgGroup struct](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.ArgGroup.html#method.conflicts_with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to introduce an [`ArgGroup`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.ArgGroup.html). To do that with the derive macros, create a struct `Group` and store it in `MyCommand`, and define it to be a group that is required but disallow multiple values:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, clap::Args)]
#[clap(name = "command")]
pub struct MyCommand {
    #[clap(flatten)]
    group: Group,
    #[clap(name = "others", long)]
    other_commands: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, clap::Args)]
#[group(required = true, multiple = false)]
pub struct Group {
    /// Argument1.
    #[clap(short, long)]
    command_a: Option<String>,
    /// Argument2.
    #[clap(short, long)]
    command_b: Option<String>,
}
```