# CLAP- make an arg conflicting with a group of arg

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

Hello i'm using [clap](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/index.html) to build a cli

What I want to achieve is simple:
I have 2 groups of args `fruits` and `vegetables`
I have a subcommand `create` to create a new fruit or vegetable

I could have 2 sepetate commands to create fruit and vegetables but I prefer to have only one command and pass an arg to create a fruit (--fruit) or a vegetable (--vegetable)

```
my_cli create --fruit // will create a fruit
my_cli create --vegetable // will create a vegetable
```

there are required args to create a fruit --weight --country
there are required args to create a vegetable --type --destination

If I run `my_cli create --fruit --type "root vegetable"` it should pop an error because --fruit will conflicts with all args from vegetable group, same for --vegetable with args from fruit group

There is my code

```rust
#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
pub struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    pub command: Commands,
    /// Apply command on fruit
    #[arg(
        short,
        long,
        global = true,
        conflicts_with = "vegetable",
        default_value = "true",
        default_value_if("vegetable", "true", "false"),
        display_order = 0
    )]
    pub fruit: bool,
    /// Apply command on vegetable
    #[arg(
        short,
        long,
        global = true,
        conflicts_with = "fruit",
        default_value = "false",
        default_value_if("fruit", "true", "false"),
        display_order = 0
    )]
    pub vegetable: bool,
}


#[derive(Subcommand)]
pub enum Commands {
    /// Create a new fruit or vegetable
    Create(CreateArgs),
}


#[derive(Args, Debug)]
pub struct CreateArgs {
    /// Type
    #[arg(long, display_order = 1, group = "vegetable_group")]
    pub type: Option<String>,
    /// Destination
    #[arg(long, display_order = 1, group = "vegetable_group")]
    pub destination: Option<String>,
    /// Weight
    #[arg(long, display_order = 1, group = "fruit_group")]
    pub weight: Option<String>,
    /// Country
    #[arg(long, display_order = 1, group = "fruit_group")]
    pub country: Option<String>,
}
```

How to make a group of args conflicts with an other?

I could do something like this for all args but with a lot of args this is not relevant

```
/// Destination
#[arg(long, display_order = 1, group = "vegetable_group", conflicts_with_all(["weight", "country"])]
pub destination: Option<String>,
```

Comment: How tied to the current CLI are you? It would be easier (and arguably more intuitive for users) to have the commands be `my_cli create fruit --weight 123 --country de` etc, where `fruit` and `vegetable` are subcommands rather than options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I require one of the two Clap options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76315540/how-do-i-require-one-of-the-two-clap-options)

Answer (score 3):

Clap subcommands names can contain dashes, so the solution is simple (if tricky):

```rust
use clap::{Parser, Subcommand};

#[derive(Parser)]
struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    command: CreateCommand,
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
enum CreateCommand {
    Create {
        #[command(subcommand)]
        fruit: FruitCommands,
    },
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
enum FruitCommands {
    #[command(name = "--fruit")]
    Fruit {
        #[arg(long)]
        weight: u32,
        #[arg(long)]
        country: String,
    },
    #[command(name = "--vegetable")]
    Vegetable {
        #[arg(long)]
        r#type: String,
        #[arg(long)]
        destination: String,
    },
}
```